# What's the best way to implement supabase auth and database in Next js?

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase, supabase-database

I'm starting an app in next js and I'm using supabase for authentication and database.

I have the authenticated users (the actual users Supabase creates) and a table called 'User', where I will store all the users data I need to handle through the app.

Actually, I have this workaround... but I'm pretty sure that there's something cleaner and performant and I'm not founding the answer.

```
function MyApp({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<{
  initialSession: Session;
}>) {
  // Create a new supabase browser client on every first render.
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() =>
    createBrowserSupabaseClient({
      supabaseUrl: supabaseUrl,
      supabaseKey: supabaseAnonKey,
    })
  );
  const session = useSession();

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<UserProps>(defaultUserDataValue);

  const getProfile = useCallback(async (id: string, email: string) => {
    const { data } = await supabase.from("user").select().eq("id", id);

    if (data !== null && data.length > 0) {
      setUserData(data[0]);
    } else {
      try {
        const { data } = await supabase.from("user").insert({
          id: id,
          name: "",
          email: email,
          username: id,
          profile_image: "",
          default_profile_img_color: pickRandom([
            "#ef4444",
            "#f97316",
            "#22c55e",
            "#8b5cf6",
            "#3b82f6",
            "#f43f5e",
          ]),
        });
        if (!data) {
          return;
        }
        setUserData(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err, "error creating user");
      }
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session && session.user.email) {
      getProfile(session.user.id, session.user.email);
    } else {
      setUserData(defaultUserDataValue);
    }
  }, [getProfile, session]);

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <UserDataContext.Provider value={userData}>
        <SessionDataContext.Provider value={session}>
          <Toaster />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </SessionDataContext.Provider>
      </UserDataContext.Provider>
    </SessionContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger within the database to sync `auth.users` to your `public.users` table:

```sql
/**
* This trigger automatically creates a user entry when a new user signs up via Supabase Auth.
*/ 
create function public.handle_new_user() 
returns trigger as $$
begin
  insert into public.users (id, full_name, avatar_url)
  values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'avatar_url');
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

You can find a full ap